# How to print a File in C# with duplex, stapling and punch?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, duplex

I'm working on a WPF application.

I have the following problem: When the user prints the documents, it should set some initial settings; such as "duplex", "stapling" and "punch". The important thing is: It shouldn't open the print dialog window, because it would be really annoying when it would pop up a print dialog window for each document.

Code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox grid = new TextBox();
        grid.Text = "test";
        System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog dialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
        PrinterSettings settings = new PrinterSettings();
        dialog.PrinterSettings = settings;
        Document document = new Document();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        document = application.Documents.Add(@"C:\deleteMe\Modulplanung.pdf");
        dialog.Document = (PrintDocument)document;
    }
```

Comment: How to set those without a Dialog? You're no being clear.

Comment: Where is your printing code? The [PrintDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class does *not* open any dialogs. The [PrintDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) appears only if you explicitly open it

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to set the settings in the code-behind. The important thing is, it should not pop up a print dialog **window**.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but I can't set duplex, stapling and punch.

Comment: I repeat, where is the code? Are you using the PrintDocument class from WinForms or the `System.Printing` classes that works with XPS files? Both accept printer settings. Eg  Duplexing and Stapling are provided as options in `System.Printing`. The System.Drawing.PrintDocument class only has settings for Duplexing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've tried both of them. How do I set up custom printer settings?My own Code doesn't work. And I cant set a punch propperty.

Comment: You need to be looking at a specific printers settings, not the dialog settings.

Comment: @PeterSmith I dont know what you mean, can you please make an example?

Comment: [See](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings(v=vs.100).aspx) for example. These seem to be the properties that are available. You can also check which are supported for a specific printer